# How to generate SSL certificate on subdomain?

Tags: java, ssl, soap, glassfish, subdomain

I actually have a hosting service who has a subdomain, that subdomain function is to redirect to my local server where I have my services, for example:

My domain: example.com

Subdomain: guaymas.example.com // His function is to redirect to my server (firewall)

Redirect to a port : guaymas.example.com:8080 // where I have my services

And through a port I have a web service, in order to make the data transfer more secure I wanted to implement a SSL certificate but because of my configuration I’ḿ not able to generate the certificate with letś encrypt (because buying one is not an option), I can’t verify with http or dns method, Is there any other method that I can use to generate the SSL certificate?

PD: I'm using GlassFish and Soap web services on JAVA, those are running on Linux Server and my distro is deepin

Thanks a lot

Comment: *"Is there any other method that I can use to generate the SSL certificate?"* Yes, but the users of your website won't trust it, and will get error messages when trying to connect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a self-signed certificate with OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl)

Comment: "I’ḿ not able to generate the certificate with letś encrypt " You do not explain why. Let's encrypt let you choose between at least a DNS or an HTTP based validation. Why neither works in your case?